# MongoDB - how to query this data

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking to retrieve some data from MongoDB but I'm unsure of how to do it efficiently. It might be that my collection/document structure isn't ideal and I need to store it in a different manner. Any advice would be appreciated..

I have two collections - objects and object views

**Objects**

```javascript
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId( "4f182ac3369a2b2603010000" ),
  "name" : "Object name",
  "project_id" : "4f182a76369a2b2903000000"
}
```

**Object views**

```javascript
{
"_id" : ObjectId( "4f182ac3369a2b2603010000" ),
  "2012" : {
    "r" : 8,
    "t" : 16,
    "u" : 10,
   }
}
```

I want to retrieve 2012.r from the 'Object views' collection for all the objects belonging to a particular project.

Here's my ideas of how to do it:

1. Have a find query that returns all the documents from the 'object
   views' collection that match the _id field. To me this doesn't seem
   efficient or a tidy way of doing things (imagine if there were 2000
   objects).
2. Add the project_id field to all the 'object views' documents, then do a find query to select all the documents that match the project_id. Is it frowned upon/efficient to select multiple documents (there could be as little as 2 or as many as 2000)?
3. Create a collection specifically for this problem. It would contain a document for each project, where each document specifies all the instances of objects belonging to that project and the values of 2012.r. Then do a find query to select the single document.

Any thoughts/advice or alternative solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add the project_id field to all the 'object views' documents, then do
>   a find query to select all the documents that match the project_id. Is
>   it frowned upon/efficient to select multiple documents (there could be
>   as little as 2 or as many as 2000)?

Definitely the way to do it (plus an index on that column), both in terms of performance (`db.object_views.find({project_id : "4f182a76369a2b2903000000" })`) and code & query simplicity.

Drivers do batching under the hood so fetching 2000 documents is not a big deal.

Comment: Easy enough then, thanks! As you say, presuming it has an index on it would you recommend storing project_id as an ObjectId or a string?

Comment: i'd use the same type as in Object.project_id

Answer (score 0):

If you have a strong background in SQL, you might find [this](http://www.querymongo.com/) SQL-MongoDB translator helpful:

However, it misses quotes in parameters when it is needed. So, watch for it.

Hope this is helpful for you